# What are the best practices for uploading 50MB file in angular+ spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, large-files

I'm writing code to upload a file size of 50 MB, what are the best practices for such scenarios, currently we are handling file size of 5 MB, there we are not doing any chunking at angular side, Can I do chunking at Angular for a 50 MB size file, does that a good approach ?

Comment: 50 mb is a huge file

Comment: If you want to process that data you have do streaming from your spring service to angular back. In angular there are couple popular npm packages which can be used to process efficient way in frontend